# How to parse XML/SGM File with invalid Elements with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, element

```
<!DOCTYPE allgemeines PUBLIC "-//DATEV//DTD Allgemein 0.1//DE" [<!-- Begin Document Specific Declarations --><!-- End Document Specific Declarations -->]>

<allgemeines dok-art="Lexikon" dok-typ="Lexikon" dok-nummer="0630268">
<biblio1><autor><person><nachname>Jauch</nachname><vorname>David</vorname></person></autor>
<daten><datum normdat="20160701"></daten>
<fundstellen><nicht-da grund="fehlt"></fundstellen>
<normen><norm><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 1 Abs. 1</unnormiert><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 1 Abs. 4</unnormiert><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 2 Abs. 7</unnormiert><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 4a Abs. 1</unnormiert><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 25 Abs. 1</unnormiert><unnormiert>EStG &sect; 49 Abs. 1 Nr. 4</unnormiert></norm></normen>
<jahre><jahr jahr="2016"></jahre></biblio1><text-alg><titel><a>Eink&uuml;nfteermittlung bei der Einkommensteuer - Lexikon des Steuerrechts</a></titel>
<inhaltsverzeichnis><inhalteintrag><inhalttext link="D063026800001"><a>1 Allgemeiner &Uuml;berblick</a></inhalttext></inhalteintrag><inhalteintrag><inhalttext link="D063026800002"><a>2 Zuordnung von Eink&uuml;nften zur unbeschr&auml;nkten und beschr&auml;nkten Einkommensteuerpflicht</a></inhalttext></inhalteintrag><inhalteintrag><inhalttext link="D063026800003"><a>3 Wirtschaftsjahr als Ermittlungszeitraum</a></inhalttext></inhalteintrag><inhalteintrag><inhalttext link="D063026800004"><a>4 Pauschbetr&auml;ge</a></inhalttext></inhalteintrag><inhalteintrag><inhalttext link="D063026800005"><a>5 Verwandte Lexikonartikel</a></inhalttext></inhalteintrag></inhaltsverzeichnis>

<kapitel><ueberschrift id="D063026800001" nummer="1">Allgemeiner &Uuml;berblick</ueberschrift>
<a>Die ESt ist eine Jahressteuer (&sect; 2 Abs. 7 Satz 1 EStG). Die Grundlagen f&uuml;r ihre Festsetzung sind demnach grunds&auml;tzlich f&uuml;r das Kj. zu ermitteln. Veranlagungszeitraum ist nach &sect; 25 Abs. 1 EStG immer das Kj., w&auml;hrend der Ermittlungszeitraum vom Kj. abweichen kann. Der Ermittlungszeitraum ist auch dann das Kj., wenn w&auml;hrend des Kj. sowohl unbeschr&auml;nkte als auch beschr&auml;nkte ESt-Pflicht besteht. Die w&auml;hrend der beschr&auml;nkten ESt-Pflicht erzielten inl&auml;ndischen Eink&uuml;nfte sind in eine Veranlagung zur unbeschr&auml;nkten ESt-Pflicht einzubeziehen (&sect; 2 Abs. 7 Satz 3 EStG (&rarr; <doknr nummer="0630648">Progressionsvorbehalt</doknr>).</a>
<a>&sect; 2 Abs. 1 bis 6 EStG regeln die Ermittlung der Eink&uuml;nfte bei der Einkommensteuer:</a>
<unnum-aufz typ="punkt"><aufz-pkt><a>Abs. 1 benennt hierbei die sieben Einkunftsarten und regelt hierbei den sachlichen Umfang der unbeschr&auml;nkten Steuerpflicht (Welteinkommensprinzip).</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Abs. 2 unterscheidet nach der Art der Einkunftsermittlung zwischen Gewinneink&uuml;nften und &Uuml;berschusseink&uuml;nften (Dualismus der Einkunftsarten).</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Abs. 3 bis 5 listet die verschiedenen Stufen der Ermittlung auf, beginnend mit Summe der Eink&uuml;nfte (&rarr; <doknr nummer="0630383">Gesamtbetrag der Eink&uuml;nfte</doknr>) bis hin zur Bemessungsgrundlage zur Ermittlung der Einkommensteuer, dem zu versteuernden Einkommen.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Abs. 5b bestimmt, dass Eink&uuml;nfte aus Kapitalverm&ouml;gen, soweit sie der Abgeltungsteuer nach &sect; 32d unterliegen, nicht in die Ermittlung des zu versteuernden Einkommens einzubeziehen sind.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Abs. 6 bestimmt zuletzt die Ermittlung der festzusetzenden Einkommensteuer.</a></aufz-pkt></unnum-aufz>
<a>Aus R 2 EStR ergibt sich folgendes Veranlagungsschema:</a><table frame="none"><tgroup cols="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="8*"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2" colwidth="6*"><colspec colnum="3" colname="3" colwidth="86*"><tbody><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>1</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a></a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Summe der Eink&uuml;nfte aus den Einkunftsarten</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>2</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&equals;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>S.d.E.</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>3</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Altersentlastungsbetrag (&sect; 24a EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>4</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Entlastungsbetrag f&uuml;r Alleinerziehende (&sect; 24b EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>5</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Freibetrag f&uuml;r Land- und Forstwirte (&sect; 13 Abs. 3 EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>6</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&plus;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Hinzurechnungsbetrag (&sect; 52 Abs. 3 Satz 5 EStG sowie &sect; 8 Abs. 5 Satz 2 AIG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>7</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&equals;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Gesamtbetrag der Eink&uuml;nfte (&sect; 2 Abs. 3 EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>8</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Verlustabzug nach &sect; 10d EStG</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>9</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Sonderausgaben (&sect;&sect; 10, 10a, 10b, 10c EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>10</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>au&szlig;ergew&ouml;hnliche Belastungen (&sect;&sect; 33 bis 33b EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>11</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Steuerbeg&uuml;nstigung der zu Wohnzwecken genutzten Wohnungen, Geb&auml;ude und Baudenkmale sowie der schutzw&uuml;rdigen Kulturg&uuml;ter (&sect;&sect; 10e bis 10i EStG, &sect; 52 Abs. 21 Satz 6 EStG i.d.F. vom 16.4.1997, BGBl I 1997, 821 und &sect; 7 F&ouml;rdG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>12</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&plus;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Erstattungs&uuml;berh&auml;nge (&sect; 10 Abs. 4b Satz 3 EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>13</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&plus;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>zuzurechnendes Einkommen gem. &sect; 15 Abs. 1 AStG</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>14</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&equals;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Einkommen (&sect; 2 Abs. 4 EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>15</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>Freibetr&auml;ge f&uuml;r Kinder (&sect;&sect; 31, 32 Abs. 6 EStG)</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>16</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>.&sol;.</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>H&auml;rteausgleich nach &sect; 46 Abs. 3 EStG, &sect; 70 EStDV</a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>17</a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>&equals;</a></entry><entry colname="3" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><a>z.v.E. (&sect; 2 Abs. 5 EStG).</a></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table><a><kursiv>Abb.: Veranlagungsschema</kursiv></a>
<a>Es existieren verschiedene Methoden je nach Art der Eink&uuml;nfte:</a>
<a>Bei &Uuml;berschusseinkunftsarten ermitteln sich die Eink&uuml;nfte als &Uuml;berschuss der Einnahmen &uuml;ber die Werbungskosten (&sect; 2 Abs. 2 Nr. 2 EStG); anzuwenden bei Eink&uuml;nften aus nichtselbstst&auml;ndiger Arbeit, aus Kapitalverm&ouml;gen, aus Vermietung und Verpachtung, sonstigen Eink&uuml;nften.</a>
<a>Bei den Gewinneinkunftsarten (Eink&uuml;nfte aus Land- und Forstwirtschaft, aus Gewerbebetrieb, aus selbstst&auml;ndiger Arbeit) sind die Eink&uuml;nfte der Gewinn (&sect; 2 Abs. 2 Nr. 1 EStG). Hinsichtlich der Gewinnermittlungsmethoden ist zu unterscheiden:</a>
<unnum-aufz typ="punkt"><aufz-pkt><a>Ermittlung des &Uuml;berschusses der Betriebseinnahmen &uuml;ber die Betriebsausgaben nach &sect; 4 Abs. 3 EStG (Einnahmen-&Uuml;berschuss-Rechnung); angewandt von Gewerbetreibenden und Land- und Forstwirten, die gesetzlich zur F&uuml;hrung und Erstellung von Abschl&uuml;ssen nicht verpflichtet sind und dies auch freiwillig nicht tun, sowie von Steuerpflichtigen mit Eink&uuml;nften aus selbstst&auml;ndiger Arbeit.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Betriebsverm&ouml;gensvergleich: Ermittlung des Unterschiedsbetrags zwischen dem Betriebsverm&ouml;gen am Schluss des Wirtschaftsjahres und dem Betriebsverm&ouml;gen am Schluss des vorangegangenen Wirtschaftsjahres, vermehrt um den Wert der Entnahmen, vermindert um den Wert der Einlagen (&sect;&sect; 4 Abs. 1 und 5 Abs. 1 EStG); anzuwenden von Steuerpflichtigen, die nach Handels- oder Steuerrecht verpflichtet sind, B&uuml;cher zu f&uuml;hren und regelm&auml;&szlig;ig Abschl&uuml;sse zu machen (&sect;&sect; 140, 141 AO; Buchf&uuml;hrungspflicht) oder die dies freiwillig tun: Land- und Forstwirte, Selbstst&auml;ndige, Nichtkaufleute nach &sect; 4 Abs. 1 EStG, Kaufleute nach &sect; 5 Abs. 1 EStG.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Ermittlung des Gewinns aus Land- und Forstwirtschaft nach Durchschnittss&auml;tzen. Diese kommt erst dann zum Ansatz, wenn weder die Einnahmen-&Uuml;berschussrechnung gew&auml;hlt wird noch eine Buchf&uuml;hrungspflicht besteht.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Ermittlung des Gewinns aus dem Betrieb von Seeschiffen im internationalen Verkehr nach pauschalierten S&auml;tzen (Tonnagesteuer; &sect; 5a EStG).</a></aufz-pkt></unnum-aufz></kapitel>
<kapitel><ueberschrift id="D063026800002" nummer="2">Zuordnung von Eink&uuml;nften zur unbeschr&auml;nkten und beschr&auml;nkten Einkommensteuerpflicht</ueberschrift>
<a>Der BFH regelt mit Urteil vom 19.12.2001 (I R 63&sol;00, BStBl II 2003, 302) die Zuordnung von Eink&uuml;nften aus nichtselbstst&auml;ndiger T&auml;tigkeit zur unbeschr&auml;nkten bzw. beschr&auml;nkten Steuerpflicht.</a>
<a><kursiv>Sachverhalt:</kursiv></a>
<beispiel>
<a>Der im Inland wohnhafte ArbN (unbeschr&auml;nkt Steuerpflichtig) ist bei der X-AG besch&auml;ftigt. Mit Wirkung zum 31.3. wird der ArbN an die Muttergesellschaft (M) in die USA versetzt. Am 8.3. zieht der ArbN in die USA um. Vom 1.1. bis zum 31.3. bescheinigt die X-AG in der Lohnsteuerbescheinigung des ArbN einen Bruttoarbeitslohn von 62&nbsp;083 &euro;. Der gesamte Bruttoarbeitslohn betr&auml;gt im ma&szlig;geblichen Kj. 188&nbsp;665 &euro;.</a></beispiel>
<a><kursiv>Entscheidungsgr&uuml;nde des BFH:</kursiv></a>
<beispiel>
<a>Bis einschlie&szlig;lich 8.3. ist der ArbN unbeschr&auml;nkt steuerpflichtig gem. &sect; 1 Abs. 1 EStG. Ab 9.3. ist der ArbN beschr&auml;nkt steuerpflichtig nach &sect; 1 Abs. 4 EStG, wenn er inl&auml;ndische Eink&uuml;nfte i.S.d. &sect; 49 Abs. 1 Nr. 4 EStG bezieht.</a>
<a>Arbeitslohn, der vor dem 9.3. zugeflossen ist, unterliegt der unbeschr&auml;nkten Steuerpflicht. Ob bestimmte Eink&uuml;nfte den Regeln &uuml;ber die unbeschr&auml;nkte Steuerpflicht unterliegen, ist nach den Verh&auml;ltnissen im Zeitpunkt des Erzielens der Eink&uuml;nfte zu beurteilen.</a><table frame="all"><tgroup cols="2" colsep="0" rowsep="0"><colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="21*"><colspec colnum="2" colname="2" colwidth="79*"><tbody><row><entry colname="1" colsep="1" rowsep="0"><a><fett>8.3. Umzug in USA</fett></a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="1" rowsep="0"><a><fett>Auszahlung Arbeitslohn durch X-AG</fett></a></entry></row><row><entry colname="1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><a></a></entry><entry colname="2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><a>Der Arbeitslohn unterliegt mit demjenigen Betrag der ESt, der sich als Gegenleistung f&uuml;r eine im Inland ausge&uuml;bte oder verwertete T&auml;tigkeit darstellt (&sect; 49 Abs. 1 Nr. 4 EStG). Es gen&uuml;gt, dass die T&auml;tigkeit im Inland ausge&uuml;bt &raquo;worden ist&laquo;. Es ist nicht erforderlich, dass der ArbN im Zeitpunkt der Lohnzahlung im Inland t&auml;tig ist und durch den Arbeitslohn die gegenw&auml;rtige T&auml;tigkeit abgegolten wird. &sect; 49 Abs. 1 Nr. 4 EStG greift auch dann ein, wenn ein im Ausland wohnender ArbN fr&uuml;her im Inland t&auml;tig war, diese T&auml;tigkeit inzwischen aufgegeben hat und nunmehr eine Nachzahlung f&uuml;r die fr&uuml;here T&auml;tigkeit erh&auml;lt.</a></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table>
<a>Unter folgenden Voraussetzungen steht die Lohnzahlung der X-AG in wirtschaftlichem Zusammenhang mit der Inlandst&auml;tigkeit des ArbN:</a>
<num-aufz typ="kl"><aufz-pkt wert="a."><a>das Arbeitsverh&auml;ltnis zwischen dem ArbN und der X-AG besteht bis zum 31.3. Die X-AG hat die Zahlung insgesamt in Erf&uuml;llung ihrer Verpflichtungen aus dem Arbeitsvertrag geleistet. In diesem Fall ist der ArbN &ndash; sei es aus Urlaubs- oder aus anderen Gr&uuml;nden &ndash; f&uuml;r die Zeit vom 9.3.an von seiner Arbeitsverpflichtung gegen&uuml;ber der X-AG freigestellt gewesen. Auch in diesem Fall beruhen s&auml;mtliche Zahlungen auf dem Arbeitsverh&auml;ltnis. Die f&uuml;r die Zeit vom 9.3. bis zum 31.3. geleistete Zahlung ist den inl&auml;ndischen Eink&uuml;nften i.S.d. &sect; 49 Abs. 1 Nr. 4 EStG zuzuordnen.</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt wert="b."><a>Dasselbe Ergebnis liegt dann vor, wenn das Arbeitsverh&auml;ltnis zwischen dem ArbN und der X-AG schon zum 8.3. aufgel&ouml;st wurde, die X-AG jedoch aus Kulanz- oder &auml;hnlichen Gr&uuml;nden auf eine K&uuml;rzung des f&uuml;r M&auml;rz geschuldeten Arbeitslohns verzichtet.</a></aufz-pkt></num-aufz>
<a>Anders w&auml;re die Rechtslage, wenn der ArbN schon zum 9.3. in die Dienste der M getreten w&auml;re und die X-AG das auf die Zeit bis zum 31.3. entfallende Gehalt f&uuml;r Rechnung der M gezahlt h&auml;tte. In diesem Fall h&auml;tte die Zahlung keinen wirtschaftlichen Bezug zu der vorausgegangenen T&auml;tigkeit des ArbN im Inland; sie w&uuml;rde sich vielmehr als Entgelt f&uuml;r die in den USA geleistete Arbeit im Dienst der M darstellen.</a>
<a>Der Arbeitslohn des ArbN ist wie folgt zuzuordnen:</a>
<unnum-aufz typ="punkt"><aufz-pkt><a>vom 1.1. bis 8.3. der unbeschr&auml;nkten Steuerpflicht,</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Arbeitslohn der X-AG ab dem 9.3. f&uuml;r eine T&auml;tigkeit, die im Inland ausge&uuml;bt worden ist, der beschr&auml;nkten Steuerpflicht und</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>Arbeitslohn der M in den USA f&uuml;r die dort ausge&uuml;bte T&auml;tigkeit darf nicht in die Bemessungsgrundlage der deutschen ESt einbezogen werden.</a></aufz-pkt></unnum-aufz>
<a>Der Arbeitslohn f&uuml;r die Zeit der T&auml;tigkeit in den USA ist jedoch gem. &sect; 32b Abs. 1 Nr. 2 EStG im Wege des Progressionsvorbehalts (&rarr; <doknr nummer="0630648">Progressionsvorbehalt</doknr>) zu ber&uuml;cksichtigen.</a></beispiel></kapitel>
<kapitel><ueberschrift id="D063026800003" nummer="3">Wirtschaftsjahr als Ermittlungszeitraum</ueberschrift>
<a>Bei Land- und Forstwirten und bei Gewerbetreibenden ist das &rarr; <doknr nummer="0630944">Wirtschaftsjahr</doknr> Ermittlungszeitraum f&uuml;r den Gewinn (&sect; 4a Abs. 1 EStG).</a></kapitel>
<kapitel><ueberschrift id="D063026800004" nummer="4">Pauschbetr&auml;ge</ueberschrift>
<a>Sofern keine h&ouml;heren tats&auml;chlichen Werbungskosten bei den &Uuml;berschusseink&uuml;nften nachgewiesen werden, sind bei der Ermittlung der Eink&uuml;nfte bestimmte Pauschbetr&auml;ge zu ber&uuml;cksichtigen.</a>
<a>Die Pauschbetr&auml;ge betragen</a>
<unnum-aufz typ="punkt"><aufz-pkt><a>bei den Eink&uuml;nften aus nichtselbstst&auml;ndiger Arbeit ein Pauschbetrag von 1&nbsp;000 &euro;,</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>bei den Eink&uuml;nften aus Kapitalverm&ouml;gen ist als Werbungskosten ein Sparer-Pauschbetrag in H&ouml;he von 801 &euro; bzw. 1&nbsp;602 &euro; f&uuml;r Verheiratete ber&uuml;cksichtigt,</a></aufz-pkt>
<aufz-pkt><a>bei bestimmten sonstigen Eink&uuml;nften gem. &sect; 22 EStG ein Pauschbetrag von 102 &euro;.</a></aufz-pkt></unnum-aufz></kapitel>
<kapitel><ueberschrift id="D063026800005" nummer="5">Verwandte Lexikonartikel</ueberschrift>
<a>&rarr; <doknr nummer="0630944">Wirtschaftsjahr</doknr></a>
<a>&rarr; <doknr nummer="0630383">Gesamtbetrag der Eink&uuml;nfte</doknr></a>
<a>&nbsp;</a><a zz.is="is-ja"><fett>Redaktioneller Hinweis:</fett><za>&copy; Sch&auml;ffer-Poeschel Verlag f&uuml;r Wirtschaft, Steuern, Recht, Stuttgart.</a></kapitel></text-alg>
<biblio2><quelle>Sch&auml;ffer-Poeschel</quelle></biblio2><allg-ang><rthemen><rthema>Lexikon</rthema></rthemen><lexikon><speziallexikon>Lexikon Steuerrecht</speziallexikon></lexikon><lexikonstichworte><lexikonstichwort>Eink&uuml;nfteermittlung bei der Einkommensteuer</lexikonstichwort></lexikonstichworte><schlagwoerter>Eink&uuml;nfteermittlung bei der Einkommensteuer</schlagwoerter></allg-ang><intern-ang><erfass erf-kuerzel="nn" normdat="20160701" koe="extern"></intern-ang></allgemeines>
```

The code above is the exact content of one of many sgm files which need to be processed.

Do you know a way to parse the data ignoring the unclosed elements like `<erfass erf-kuerzel="nn" normdat="20160701" koe="extern">` with PHP?

I was not able to find an appropriate parser, so any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean because of the missing close tag?  SGML allows this but XML does not. You cannot use an XML parser to parse SGML that is not constrained to valid XML.  You could look at Python's `sgmllib` but it is not clear that it is a full SGML parser.  It seems to be the abstract base for `htmllib`.

Comment: Does that mean you already tried using `DOMDocument` with `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`?

Comment: yes, I mean because of the missing close tag. And yes, I also tried with DOMDocument, but still cant access the required data: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->load($file);
    $data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('allgemeines');   
    var_dump($data);die; `

Comment: I'm 99% sure you could have made your example [more minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$allgemeines = $doc->getElementsByTagName('allgemeines')->item(0);
```